# ETH_P_IPV6 in dev_start_xmit

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, driver, kernel-module

I have a network driver(called gtp - a udp encapsulation protocol) as kernel module implemented in Openwrt system and a netlink library to control the driver by opening sockets and etc. The driver seems to work fine, but when kernel calls gtp_start_xmit() with .ndo_start_xmit() pointer, the skb passed to this function has protocol 0x86dd (ETH_P_IPV6) such that ntohs(skb->protocol)=0x86dd. I was hoping to see 0x0800 (ETH_P_IP) instead. I dont know how the ethernet frame goes to my driver with this field. Could someone help me figure it out?

The netlink library opens socket as:

```
int fd1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);                        
struct sockaddr_in sockaddr_fd1 = {
    .sin_family = AF_INET,
    .sin_port   = htons(3386),
    .sin_addr   = {
        .s_addr     = INADDR_ANY,
    },
};                                                                   
if (bind(fd1, (struct sockaddr *) &sockaddr_fd1,
     sizeof(sockaddr_fd1)) < 0) {
    perror("bind");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

also my device is big endian.

Comment: Ethernet is a layer-2 protocol, and it really doesn't know or care which layer-3 protocols it carries. The EtherType field simply tells it to which layer-3 module the payload of the frame should be passed.

Comment: @RonMaupin yes, but the driver only supports for ETH_P_IP frames, so when other EtherType comes, it simply returns -EOPNOTSUPP. (operation not supported). Why the kernel calls the driver's ndo_start_xmit function by giving skb with  ETH_P_IPV6 frame? Another thing is that I see this  happening twice from dmesg. The kernel does not call the driver's xmit function anymore, though I route packets to driver's interface.